# How to pass environment variables when programmatically starting a new Amazon EC2 from image?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, ec2-ami, ec2-api-tools

I am using AWS Java API RunInstance() to start a  new EC2 instance from my custom AMI image. How do I pass environment variables  to the new EC2  INSTANCE  such as database url, AWS credentials etc.  ?

Answer (score 13):

http://alestic.com/2009/06/ec2-user-data-scripts explains how to do this with user-data. for gotchas about using Java see [AmazonEC2 launch with userdata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7491839/amazonec2-launch-with-userdata).

note that I've seen mention that this doesn't work with Windows, only Unix.

[update] more data on setting environment variables here: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=139744

[after much testing] for me, echoing the environment variables into /etc/environment works best, like this:

```
 reservation = connection.run_instances(image_id = image_id,
  key_name = keypair,
  instance_type = 'm1.small',
  security_groups = ['default'],
  user_data = '''#!/bin/sh\necho export foozle=barzle >> /etc/environment\n''')
```

then upon login:

```
ubuntu@ip-10-190-81-29:~$ echo $foozle
barzle
```

Answer (score 8):

DISCLAIMER: I am not a sys admin!

I use a secure S3 bucket meaning a bucket that only the instance you're launching has access to.  You can setup an IAM role that looks like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-secure-bucket/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then you can upload your `.env` file in that bucket (store it encrypted).  Then to access it on your EC2 instance, you could use the AWS cli tools:

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-pip (for aws s3 CLI library)
sudo pip install awscli
aws s3 cp --region us-east-1 s3://some-secure-bucket/.some-dot-env-file output_file_path
```

You can pull this file down when the code runs or optionally make it happen at boot by putting the aforementioned `cp` command in an init script located somewhere like `/etc/init.d/download_credentials.sh`

I think this is a really good option for downloading things that every instance using an AMI needs like credentials.  However, if you want to specify per instance metadata, I just implemented using tags which I think works nice.  To do this, alter the above IAM role with something more like:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:Get*",
        "s3:List*"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::some-secure-bucket/*"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstances",
        "ec2:DescribeTags"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

Then install `ec2-api-tools`

```
sudo sed -i.dist 's,universe$,universe multiverse,' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y ec2-api-tools
```

And now you should be able to get per instance metadata through tags, such as the "Name" of your instance:

```
ec2-describe-tags --filter resource-id="$(ec2metadata --instance-id)" --filter "key=Name" | cut -f5
```

Note: I suck at bash so I'm stripping the name in ruby but you could use `tr` to remove the newline if you're into it!

Comment: Great solution, Tony. I've ended up doing something similar, but I put my full `Instance-Init.sh` script in an encrypted bucket and pull it in upon instantiation. My actual `User-Data` script is just installing Python, pip, was-cli, and then downloading and running the 'real' `Instance-Init.sh` script. You can see my similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29932355/is-it-secure-to-store-ec2-user-data-shell-scripts-in-a-private-s3-bucket. But the big question is, is this actually secure?

Comment: Great question @AJB.  If I had that question, I would talk to AWS support directly and chat with them about "how secure" because that is really the question.  I know it is "secure enough" for my use case.  An ops person could probably dig into deeper detail.  Also on an unrelated note, I am currently using "user data" instance of the tags as I found tags to be a huge pain to manage from an instance lifecycle perspective

Answer (score 5):

You can also use instance metadata retrieval as explained at https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instancedata-data-retrieval.html

From the above document, the following GET request would retrieve user data for an instance if you run it from within the instance:

```
GET http://169.254.169.254/latest/user-data
```

This way, user data can be retrieved dynamically even after the instance is already started and running.